# General application of analytic geometry in plane geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

Can I apply linear algebra/analytic geometry to all or at least most Euclidean plane geometry problems? If so, could you recommend materials to study analytic geometry for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Geometry: A Comprehensive Course* by Pedoe is great for this.

The book is full of interesting material, and many of the theorems and exercises are of the kind you're asking for.

The prerequisites in linear algebra are quite modest.

A more old-fashioned book (which deemphasizes vector methods in comparison with more recent books), but one which goes to a very high level, would be *Analytical Geometry* by Robson.